# Object , Android

Tags: android

I created the simple application `App`, the user enters his name in EditText and click on "Enter here" button and store his name in String variable that is instance variable then will move to another activity "activity_welcome" and will display his name in TextView

My problem:
when I create an object from `Main` Class to get the variable name in `welcome` Class when running this app, the name do not store in TextView that means that
the object `main` refers to null

My question:
why object `main` refer to `null`?

When I make the variable `name` as a static variable the app will display the name in TextView that mean that object `main` store the value of name variable

Note:

Main class

```
package code.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText ;
    String name ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText=findViewById(R.id.et) ;
    }

    public void Go (View v){
        name=editText.getText().toString() ;
        Intent intent= new Intent(this,Welcome.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ba"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >

     <EditText
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="50dp"
         android:hint="Enter Your Name"
         android:textColorHint="#000"
         android:id="@+id/tv1"
         android:textColor="#000"
         android:background="#ffffff"/>

     <Button
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="50dp"
         android:text="Enter Here"
         android:background="#645353"
         android:onClick="Go"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Welcome Class

```
package code.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        textView =findViewById(R.id.tv);
        Main  main  =new Main () ;
        Toast.makeText(this,main.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //  this Toast donot display any thing
        textView.setText(main.name);
    }
}
```

activity_welcome

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You shouldn't create an `Activity` instance with `new` but with `startActivity()` generally

Comment: i'm sorry i don't understand this answer

Comment: He's saying that you shouldn't do this: 
`Main  main  =new Main () ;`
Instead, you should start an activity using `startActivity(this, Main.class);`. You shouldn't create activities using the `new()` operator, save instances of them in variables, nor operate on them as if they were normal objects.

Comment: I mean from  Main main = new Main () ; that create object from Main class to hold the value of instance variable name by object main not start activity.

Comment: @Jack You're not allowed to instantiate Activities that way, because doing so results in a null/invalid context being attached to the activity activity. In order for the Android Activity lifecycle to work properly, you have to let Android do the instantiation for you.

Comment: yes , i understood this , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just keep it simple and put string inside your intent when you go to another activity, obtain intent, and then string from the intent.

```
public void Go (View v){
    name=editText.getText().toString() ;
    Intent intent= new Intent(this,Welcome.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", name);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Obtain it in your welcome activity like this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    textView =findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if(intent!=null) {
         String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
         Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         textView.setText(name);
    }
}
```